# Uploading Image from Android client to Node.js server

Tags: android, node.js, android-asynctask

I want to upload an image from android device to node server. Currently I am converting the image to Base64 string and passing it using AsyncTask. I don't understand what's happening on the server side. It displays 'undefined' when I log the request body to the console.

**This is the android code for converting image to Base64 string and uploading to node server:**

[image]

**This is the console output after receiving the image data:**

[image]

**This is the server code:**

[image]

What can be done to rectify the error?
Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Please share the server side impacted code. The cmd prompt screenshot you shared not helpful at all

Comment: Not in the comment put that in question also the entry file code as well may be index.js file

Comment: You need to setup body-parsor configuration in order to get req.body

Comment: If you can share entry file code then it’s easy for anyone to suggest you what you need to do to get the data

Comment: Thank you for you request. I have done as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install body-parser module

To install

```
 npm i -s body-parser
```

Then

Set the below config before app.post route

```
  // support parsing of application/json type post data
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  //support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post 
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      parameterLimit: 100000,
      limit: '150mb',
      extended: true
   }));
```

Comment: Looks like your request payload is larger than 50mb so You need to know how much size are you sending from Ui and change the limit accordingly in backend. Say if you are sending 100mb file from Ui then change limit to at least 150mb like that

Comment: For the below mentioned code data gets received. But the data received is not same as data sent from the android device.I think some additional data is getting appended. app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"3mb"})); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ parameterLimit: 10000, extended: true })) app.post('/upload',function(req,resp) { console.log(req.body); });

Comment: I am not sure about how android works but from backend side that is how you need to deal with it.  Are you not able to access the required data using req.body?

Comment: For the code mentioned above I can see the data. But the thing is that some extra content is getting appended after the actual data. And I am not able to understand how to avoid the appending of that extra content.

Comment: Ok not sure about that but I suspect android code making that modification.

Comment: This is the configuration you have to do in backend to deal with request payload from Ui. Hope my answer helped resolving your original issue. Please do upvote and accept the answer

Comment: @HarshalChavan Can you tell me whether my solution resolved your issue or not?